# WPF Binding ListBox and TabItems

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, tabitem

New to WPF, am trying to do something basic (I think!). I have a TabControl and a ListBox that shows what tabitems are open:

```
<ListBox Width="170" Height="188" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, ElementName=tabControl}" Name="ListTabs" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="27">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
                    El
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Is it possible to bind to specific tabitems (tabitem2 and tabitem3) rather than the whole tabcontrol? Reason being is the first tabitem1 is a welcome tab and I don't want it to be shown in the listbox.

**UPDATE:**

Would someone be so kind to post some code on how to use an IValueConverter to hide/filter a tabitem? I have been searching for hours with no luck. Many many thanks!

Comment: I would do it with ViewModel and two different properties. Another way is to set Visibility=Collapsed inside ListBoxItem ControlTemplate on certain conditions with DataTrigger. But this solution doesn't seem to be a good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current set up the only way would be to run it through an [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx).

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <converters:StripOutFirstTabConverter x:Key="StripOutFirstTabConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <ListBox Width="170" Height="188" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, ElementName=tabControl, Converter={StaticResource StripOutFirstTabConverter}}" Name="ListTabs" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="27">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
                    El
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     </ListBox>
```

If you were willing to modify your approach you could bind the `ListBox.ItemsSource` to a [ICollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.aspx) and then make use of the `Filter` property.

```
public ICollectionView Tabs
{
    get 
    {
        if (_view == null)
        {
            _view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(tabControl.Items);
            _view.Filter = Filter;
        }

        return _view;
    }
}

private bool Filter(object arg)
{
    //arg will be a TabItem, return true if you want it, false if you don't
}
```

Comment: many thanks to everyone who responded. i will do a little research on how to implement the IValueConverter. kinds regards!

Comment: just getting back at this project and wondering if you could post some code for a ivalueconverter? i've been trying to find some samples online that have to do with tabitem or tab headers and not having much luck. many thanks!

Comment: @Easton Ronaldo If you understand how the IValueConverter works; then it is pretty straightforward. The code for filtering is mocked already for you. Review the varying links in my answer and I'm betting it will make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to filter out the welcome tab so you will need to add a Filter on a [CollectionView](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=31) Instead of binding to the items of the tab control you'd bind to the collectionview.

Although a ValueConverter might work, I consider that a kind of hack.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a converter to ItemSource and then in the converter remove the welcome page or do any changes that you want .

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not doing this. Use a common data source instead with both Listbox and Tabcontrol.

To filter/intercept any data binding, you can use IValueConverter.